# How do I find the zeroes of this summation?

Tags: summation, roots

Pretty straightforward problem, I have a summation and no idea how to find its zeroes.

I need to find the zeroes in terms of $x$ for any array of positive constants $a_0, a_1, ..., a_n$.

Summation:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{-x^2+3a_ix-2(a_i)^2}{(a_i)^2 \lvert x-a_i\rvert}$$

Note that the upper polynomial is factorable as $(x-a_i)(-x+2a_i)$, if that helps.

Comment: Might need more information on the $a_i$...

Comment: @SimpleArt It's the $i$th item of the array of constants i mention in the problem?

Comment: That's not enough information.  You will see the best I can do with this information momentarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, sort the $a_i$ in increasing order.
The $a_i$ divide the real line into $n+1$ intervals, on each of which your summand is linear, since $(x - a_i)/|x - a_i| = \pm 1$.  It's easy to find the zeros of a linear function.

Answer (score 0):

I will be using $k$ instead of $i$ just for personal preference.

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(x-a_k)(-x+2a_k)}{(a_k)^2|x-a_k|}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\text{sgn}(x-a_k)(-x+2a_k)}{a_k^2}$$

where $\text{sgn}(\mu)$ is the sign (+/-) of $\mu$.

For any negative $x$ value, we have

$$\text{sgn}(x-a_k)=-1$$

Also see that $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\text{sgn}(x-a_k)(-x+2a_k)}{a_k^2}$ has only one root by the fundamental theorem of algebra.

So, if we assume the root occurs for $x<\min(a_k)$, we will have

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\text{sgn}(x-a_k)(-x+2a_k)}{a_k^2}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2a_k-x}{a_k^2}$$

Sadly, it is clear that for any negative number $x$, the summation will be larger than $0$.

Assume the root occurs at $x>2\max(a_k)$ so that we may have $\text{sgn}(x-a_k)=1$

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\text{sgn}(x-a_k)(-x+2a_k)}{a_k^2}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2a_k-x}{a_k^2}$$

This time we see that for any $x>2\max(a_k)$, the result will be a negative value, so that will not be a root.

I cannot manage to conclude anything beyond this, so the best answer I can give you is

> $$\min(a_k)<x<\max(a_k)$$